# Flipping Layout in Altium

Tags: altium, layout

I would like to flip my entire layout from bottom to top side. The flip action should be through the board. Which means that the connectors should not change position (X-Y wise).

[image: Altium Layout Board Concept]

I hope you can give some ideas without me routing everything again.

Thanks in advance

Addition: I was hoping to do this without routing anything (or a big part) again.

Edit: I am an Altium beginner, all tips are welcome

Comment: Is it enough to flip the view and then place & route the connector again?

Comment: So what you mean to describe is to move your viewpoint to the component side from the non- component side where it is now - because if you "flip" physically the board then the connector has to move.

Comment: @Araho: might be... It's something I can try.

Comment: @Solar Mike: It doesn't matter if the components move, but the connectors should stay at the same place. It's mirrored through the board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me whether this will preserve the orientation as you hope, but you can try this:

1. Shift-click all the objects to be moved (you can also shift-drag a
   box around them).  Don't include any vias.
2. Shift-doubleclick one of the selected items.  The PCB Inspector dialog should pop up.  Properties which are common to all objects will appear here.
3. If every object selected is on the bottom layer, you should See "Bottom Layer" next to "Layer" (Otherwise you will see <...>).  Click on this and change it to "Top Layer".

Comment: This only works if you have one layer. I have both top and bottom layers. If I would change the bottom to top I would have a problem sorting the top to bottom traces out.. But I appreciate the help!

Comment: You can select all of the top layer items as above and then press Ctrl+1 to save the selection. Then select the items on the bottom layer as above and press Ctrl+2 to save the selection. You can press Alt+1 to select the top layer items and continue from step 2 above, then Alt+2 to select the original bottom otems and continue from step 2 above again.

Comment: I think this answer is the best, in addition, the comment Matthew made also helped a lot. The CTRL+1 and ALT+1 selection savers can make the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Probably just change the colour coding in Altium.

1. Mine has blue set as bottom layer and red as Top layer.
2. You can press 'L' to enter the configuration dialog box.
3. Double click on the color to change
4. Replace the bottom color layer with the top and voila!
5. Note that this should be set to original once you complete this design. I'd also recommend to close all other projects while you attempt to do this to avoid any mishap.

Comment: How could this work? Is the color connected to a specific layer? Isn't this user configurable? Don't really understand this solution...

Comment: Altium has different colors assigned to each layer. If you reverse the colors for top to bottom and bottom to top, the design would flip while all components being untouched. Though you'll have to do some redesign as well.